# max of ratios of norms (condition number)

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, condition-number

I'm reading about condition numbers on Wikipedia, and in the section on matrices it says that
$$
\left(\max_{e \neq 0} \frac {\left\Vert A^{-1}e\right\Vert }{\left\Vert e\right\Vert }\right)\cdot \left(\max_{b \neq 0} \frac {\left\Vert b\right\Vert }{\left\Vert A^{-1}b\right\Vert } \right) = 
\left(\max_{e \neq 0}  \frac {\left\Vert A^{-1}e\right\Vert }{\left\Vert e\right\Vert } \right)\cdot \left(\max_{x \neq 0} \frac {\left\Vert Ax\right\Vert }{\left\Vert x\right\Vert } \right).
$$
($A$ is a non-singular $n\times p$ matrix, and $b$ is a $p\times 1$ vector.)
As far as I can tell this means that
$$
\left(\max_{b \neq 0} \frac {\left\Vert b\right\Vert }{\left\Vert A^{-1}b\right\Vert } \right) = 
 \left(\max_{x \neq 0} \frac {\left\Vert Ax\right\Vert }{\left\Vert x\right\Vert } \right),
$$

which I can't figure out how to prove. It's probably some stunningly obvious property of norms, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is. FWIW, at this point in the article, it has not been specified *which* norm is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter which norm is used.  If we make the substitution $b = Ax$, we have
$$
\max_{b \neq 0} \frac{\|b\|}{\|A^{-1}b\|} = 
\max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|(Ax)\|}{\|A^{-1}(Ax)\|} = 
\max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}
$$

Comment: ohhh, because b=Ax=0 iff x=0, because A is a linear operator? Thank you!

Comment: Strange notation there.  $A$ is an *invertible* linear operator, so $Ax = 0 \iff  x = 0$.

Comment: Right, thanks! I fixed it.